# attiny85: example of OC1B/!OC1B output?

Tags: timer, pwm, attiny

I have a piezo transducer hooked up to 2 of my attiny85 pins, and I'm driving it via software in AC mode @4khz using a timer and interrupt.

I would like to switch this over to a hardware solution (no interrupt) using OC1B/!OC1B (PB4,PB3), but I'm not sure if it does what I think it does (inverts, OC1B/pb4 = !OC1B/pb3).

Can someone supply pointers or an example that uses OC1B/!OC1B, or how I configure it for inverted output @4khz?

Comment: Can you describe the waveform you are trying to generate? Just a 4Khz square wave?

Comment: yes, a square wave. thx.